# Ajax request using Javascript not working in iPhone browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

For iPhone browser ajax request using javascript is not working,i used the following code for ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type: type,
    url:requestURL,
    dataType: "text",
    success: successCallback,
    error: function (request, ajaxOptions, exception){
            alert(request.status);
            alert(exception);
        }  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` is not on your `iPhone (or iPhone simulator)`

If your machine and iphone are within the same (wireless) network, replace localhost with your machine's IP address and it will work fine.

Or better way, upload your files to some free domain and the test it using the hostname/domain name/ip address of the server

Comment: i tried this but doesn't work for iphone browser(it work for ie)

Comment: Did it work on your desktop browser after uploading to some server?

Comment: are you using `jQuery `mobile?

Comment: In your `mobileinit` function add this line
`$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;` and it will work fine. http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the datatype:"text". remove the datatype option from your ajax request.Do it like this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: type,
    url:requestURL,  
    success: successCallback,
    error: function (request, ajaxOptions, exception){
            alert(request.status);
            alert(exception);
        }  

});
```

Comment: i tried this but not working for iphone browser it shows the error "Error: Access is denied" for iPhone Browser.

Comment: may be cross origin issue what is the requestURL

Comment: Localhost means there should be some IIS instance running in your computer. But iphone dont have IIS . publish it in server and check it

Comment: i Publish it, but doesn't work for iphone browser(it work for ie)